# How to get parts of a file with KSOAP2 from webservice and create zip?

Tags: java, android, web-services, zip, ksoap2

I need to get a file in parts from web service. The web service gives me split the file. I send as parameters (the part that I need and size of bytes) previously already know how many parts are in total and their respective weight.

How I can get these parts with **KSOAP2** and then create a **.zip**?

```
byte[] bytess = SomeDecode(MyMethodWS (10, 1024)); //example Part 10 of 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted for a basic solution: connect and disconnect through a "for" asking bits and bytes to ws. Given that the last part to be asked should be well calculated (numberBytes).

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true); //Important that 'true'.

int numberBytes =  1024; //if numberBytes < 'sizefile' then = sizefile
int numberPart = 0; //

int parts = sizefile/numberBytes; // if the result is decimal must add +1

for(int b=0;b<parts;b++){

    //Calculate the part to be ordered: 0...numberBytes+1 ...n+1 ...n+1
    numberPart = functionCalculate(numberBytes,sizefile,b);

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo p1 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("part");
    pi.setValue(numberPart);
    pi.setType(int.class);
    Request.addProperty(p1);

    PropertyInfo p2 = new PropertyInfo();
    p2.setName("bytess");
    p2.setValue(numberBytes);
    p2.setType(int.class);
    Request.addProperty(p2);

    Blah blah ksoap code…
    Blah blah ksoap code…

    try{

        Blah blah ksoap code…
        Blah blah ksoap code…

        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();                         
        bytes = response.toString().getBytes(“UTF-8”);                      
        fos.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);//It is a zip. no need to build a zip    
    }catch(...
}//end for

close fos
```